# django can't read my regex

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i make an app called `videos`  and it works correctly , but i want to make a forked page from `videos` page which url looks like this  `videos/1,2,3,4,....`

but i get a 404 error that says:

```
Using the URLconf defined in newproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    1. videos/ [name='index']
    2. videos/ ^(?P<quran_id>[0-9]+)$ [name='detail']
    3. admin/
The current path, videos/1/, didn't match any of these.
```

i think the error was in the previous second url and i think that django can't read my regular expression .

that is my videos/urls :

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index , name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<quran_id>[0-9]+)$' , views.detail , name = 'detail'),]
```

thanks to read

Comment: The `detail` url pattern doesn't allow a slash at the end.  i.e. it would match `videos/1` but not `videos/1/`, which is what you tried to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a trailing slash `/` in the URL you're trying to fetch, and yet your `videos/urls.py` does not allow for a trailing slash.

You should change the URL pattern to `r'^(?P<quran_id>[0-9]+)/?$'` if you want to allow for an optional trailing slash in the URL.

Comment: thanks for helping ....but i just restart my server ...and every thing is good ...thanks for your answer ..